# How do I get the Simba ODBC driver to run from Excel - Currently get "Unexpected error: Container exited unexpectedly with code 0x40000015.' eror

Tags: excel, ms-access, google-bigquery, odbc

I'm attempting to use the Simba ODBC driver to get to my Google BigQuery data and am not able to do so.  I've attempted with both User Authentication and Service Authentication with the same results.  I'm able to configure the DNS successfully, and clicking the dropdowns for "Catalog (Project)" and "Dataset" work correctly and give lists of the data that is on Google BigQuery.  Even clicking the "Test" button in the setup says "Success! Successfully connected to the data source".  However, when I go into Excel, select "Get data" off the ribbon for "Data", and choose "From Other Sources"/"From ODBC" and select the DNS I created above, it shows a treeview of the project, but when I expand it I get the error "Unexpected error: Container exited unexpectedly with code 0x40000015. PID: 24520.
Used features: Odbc.DataSource/Simba ODBC Driver for Google BigQuery/2.5.0.1001/BigQuery/2." so am unable to select the dataset.

I've also tried to use that DNS from Access but it just causes Access to crash (closes the current db).

What am I missing?  Is there a better driver to use?

Note: Both Excel and Access are from  Microsoft 365 Apps for business (subscription).  An update did not help.  I also tried removing and reinstalling the Simba driver.

Answer (score 0):

So, the fix for this was to unload version 2.5.0.1001 of the Simba ODBC driver, and load the previous version (2.4.6.1015) instead.